# Why MongoDB C# driver database no implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using EntityFramework, ADO.NET, e.t.c, we always use using operator when create context, etc.

Why MongoDB not implement IDisposable interface, for using like this without create own abstact architecture:

```
using (var database = _mongoDbFactory.GetDatabase("dbName"))
{
   .....
}
```

When i use current syntax I feel discomfort, like my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at Mongo's source to know for sure, but most likely it's because that database context is being constructed completely of managed resources in .Net.

IDisposable generally only really needs implementation if there are system resources allocated other than managed memory (such as native libraries, etc).

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I am talk not about Finalization for unmanaged resources. We want more standartized useful tool

Comment: Implementation of `IDisposable` doesn't make anything more or less "standardized".  If you're looking for `GetDatabase` to return something that implements `IDisposable` so it matches EF's pattern of use, that's possible by either forking Mongo and modifying the output of that method, or write a wrapper for  `GetDatabase()` so that it always returns something that implements `IDisposable`.